# bootstrap notify ajax succes response

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, bootstrap-notify

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(document).on('change', '#avatar', function(){
                var property = document.getElementById("avatar").files[0];

                    var form_data = new FormData();
                    form_data.append("avatar", property);

                    $.ajaxSetup({
                        beforeSend: function(xhr, type) {
                            if (!type.crossDomain) {
                                xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'));
                            }
                        },
                    });

                    $.ajax({
                        url: '{{ url('app()->getLocale())/profile') }}', 
                        method: "POST",
                        data: form_data,
                        contentType: false,
                        cache: false,
                        processData: false,
                        success:function(response){
                            window.location.href = window.location.href;

                            $.notify({
                                message: 'Hello World' 
                            },{
                            // settings
                            type: 'danger'
                            });

                        }
                    })
            });
       });
    </script>
```

How can I do this so that when the image is finished uploading and the image is refreshed to display a message using $ .notify? I tried everything I found on the internet, but to no available...

Comment: what are you trying to do here window.location.href = window.location.href ? reload content? because this will reload the page, and this will cancel your ajax,  open your dev console f12 on brawser, see network tab /XHR, then reload see how request is working

Comment: is a form to upload an image (avatar) for the user without the submit button and with auto refresh. But I want after the page loads to display a message with $ .notify ..